# Page not found at /about/. The current path, about/, did not match any of these. Why can't django follow my URL path?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm sure this question has been asked many times before but I'm sure I'm doing everything exactly as the tutorial says and it's still not working. I can access the home page just fine but not the about page.

Here is screenshot of the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFNAJ.png

I have the URL path in my .urls file (file below)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name='main-home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='main-about'),
]
```

And in the .urls file I have referenced the .views file (below)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def homepage(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Home</h1>')


def about(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>About</h1>')
```

I could be missing something blatantly obvious but I've been staring at this for hours now and still can't figure out why it can't find the page.

EDIT: I am referring to the app urls file in the main post. In case its useful, here is the project .urls file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('homepage/', include('home.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Is this urls.py file from your main project folder, or from an app directory (created with manage.py startapp command)?  If it's in an app, the paths need to be referenced from the main project as well.

Comment: @AlecZ Have just edited the post to be clearer. This is the app urls file. I have included the project urls file at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then `prefixed` your `url` with `homepage` as

```
localhost:8000/homepage/about/
```

It's always better to use [**{% url %} [Django-doc]**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tags for `urls` inside `templates` which will point to your `correct` url even after you change `url` path but with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Per your copied image, you're accessing localhost:8000/about, not loaclhost:8000/homepage/about, which I think if you were to visit right now would return your "about" view HttpResponse object.

The main site urls.py is referencing 'homepage/', so for anything with that prefix it will be looking at the additional path objects/parameters in your app urls.py.  Try:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls')),
]
```